# Asmx Webservice compression/de-compression?

Tags: web-services, asmx

I am developing a traditional ASP.Net web service i.e. an asmx  web service, that will be exposed to .Net and also non-.Net clients. Is it possible to implement automatic compression and de-compression for this asmx even when its consumed by a non-.Net client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you can do is to try to get IIS to do automatic compression for you. ASMX has no ability to do compression.

Is there a reason you can't use WCF? ASMX should not be used for new development unless absolutely necessary.